# I cant assign an object in the boolean modifier

Tags: mesh, modifiers, objects, transforms, scale

I would like to make a hole in a cube but I can't select any object in in the boolean modifier's "object". When i take the pipette and place it on the cylinder it is written "cube".

Comment: I can't select an object in the boolean modifier*

Comment: There are quite a few little 'gotcha's' it could be. Could you post a screen-grab including the Outliner, and the modifier panel, maybe a bit of the 3D View, so we can see some possibilities?

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your post 
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add images show your 
current setup and illustrate the problem.See [How to upload an image 
to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)

Comment: You can only use Mesh objects as a boolean